# Inserting values into input tag via buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, calculator

I am making a calculator just for fun to learn about Javascript (I know HTML & CSS very well)and I have the basis of the calculator made. I wanted to make it so that you just use the buttons. The buttons work and all. But for example if I wanted to insert 11, that wouldn't be possible because I can only insert single digits and I don't know why :(
Here is the button you press to insert the number 1.

```
<button type="button" onclick="no1 ()">1</button>
```

This is the javascript to insert he number 1 into the input tag:

```
var currentinput= document.getElementById("firstnumber");

var answer= document.getElementById("answer");
function no1 ()
{
currentinput.value=1;
answer.value=1;
}
```

How would I able to insert 11 instead of just 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add something at the end of variable, you could use something like this:

```
function no1 ()
{
    currentinput.value = currentinput.value+"1";
    answer.value=1;
}
```

this will take numbers already in the currentinput.value and add 1 at the end.

Comment: Where do I put this code in my function. I've tried but it shows 11 at the same time and I can't insert another 1 after that...

Comment: @user2867973 if function `no1()` is the function, that should insert number 1 into `currentinput` then you should replace the line `currentinput.value=1` with my suggestion. So every time you call out function `no1()`, currentinput gets the number it had before and one aditional 1. I'm not sure why you have line `answer.value=1` in that function tho. answer should be calculated based on the math operation in my oppinion and therefore should be put into another function.